# Unix timestamp in milliseconds in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, apache-kafka, timestamp, avro

I'm streaming data from Kafka topic to PostgreSQL in Avro format.
Column `time` contains Unix time in following format:

```
"time": "1645196215"
"time": "1645196215.3"
"time": "1645196215.34"
"time": "1645196215.36"
"time": "1645196215.3799999"
"time": "1645196215.3999999"
"time": "1645196215.4199998"
```

If I take this `1645196215.36` value for example I can remove "." and add `0` this will get me `1645196215360` which can be converted `select extract(epoch FROM 1645196215360) * 1000`  in PostgreSQL.

How to round other types of numbers considering I have to pass it in Avro format in PostgreSQL datetime with milliseconds precision?

My idea is to add `000` when there is nothing after `.`, add `00` if there is one digit after `.` and so on...is there better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to do this in such a complicated fashion. You could simply call `to_timestamp` on the value:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1645196215.36);

       to_timestamp        
═══════════════════════════
 2022-02-18 15:56:55.36+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: And in what data type you suggest I should serialize these values? I assume only string will work - tried int, float, long but it didn't work ok.

Comment: Huh? `timestamp` of course. There is no alternative.

Comment: I'm using Avro serializer and timestamp format doesn't get converted properly in posgreslq  (timestamp-millis logical type annotates an Avro long) : https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Timestamp+%28millisecond+precision%29 Thats why I'm using just string and doing conversion (simple way as you explained) on PostgreSQL end. My question was regarding serialization format for transfer for different types of input...

Comment: Still, if you store timestamps in a database, the type should be `timestamp`.